# How to use existing VPC in AWS CloudFormation template for new SecurityGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am trying to EC2 instance (new), Security group (new) and VPC(existing). Here is my cloudformation template.

When I run the template in Stack, I got error as `*"Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty"*`. How to solve this?

**Template:**

```
Parameters:
  VPCID:
    Description: Name of an existing VPC
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large
  AccessLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to access to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref 'InstanceSecurityGroup'
      KeyName: !Ref 'KeyName'
      ImageId: !Ref 'ImageId'   
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPCID
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref 'AccessLocation'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroups) can **only be used for default VPC**. Since you are explicitly assigning `VPCID` to `InstanceSecurityGroup`, this will be considered as non-default, resulting in failed deployment.

You **must** use [SecurityGroupIds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroupids) (not `SecurityGroups`) in your case as your VPC use will be considered as **non-default**:

```
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt 'InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId'
```

Comment: You solved a related mystery for me.  I was setting the `subnetid` for an instance to a non default VPCID, and also using the `securitygroups` property and getting the most obscure message and trying to figure out how a groupName had anything to do with my subnet setting. I switched to SecurityGroupIds and all fixed... 

`The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination`

Answer (score 0):

The error in `EC2Instance` resource in `SecurityGroups` attribute. `SecurityGroups` needs an array of `GroupId` but when you use `!Ref InstanceSecurityGroup` this returns `ResourceId`. So you need to use `GetAtt` instead to get `GroupId`.

```
Parameters:
  VPCID:
    Description: Name of an existing VPC
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large
  AccessLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to access to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId
      KeyName: !Ref 'KeyName'
      ImageId: !Ref 'ImageId'   
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPCID
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref 'AccessLocation'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html